# How to search for a string in a line and return line and line numbers in linux?

Tags: linux

I want to search for a string in a file, and the output should give me the line number and line containing that string.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `grep` with the `-n` flag. Note that line numbers are 1-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep for this.

```
grep -n yourString yourFile
```

Comment: While some questions benefit from multiple perspectives or different proposed solutions, this answer seems to add very little not already covered by soandos' answer from several months prior. Is there some way you can [edit] your answer to differentiate it from the earlier answer?

Answer (score 0):

The general tool for searching in text files is `grep`. To run it as you need, just try

```
grep -n -F "my string" files
```

The `-F` tells `grep` to search for exact matches of the string. Otherwise, `grep` searches for *regular expressions*.

`-n` tells `grep` to return line numbers as well.